# Suitable driver not found- Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

In advance I'm a  begginer for java spring mvc.

```
  try{

Connection connection = 
     DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/emidwify?user=root&password=root");

   Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;

   resultset =statement.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM childdetails") ;
%>

 <div class="div_box">
    <select>
        <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <option><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
<div align ="justify">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success active">View Details</button>
           </div>
            </div>

<%

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         out.println("wrong entry "+e);
    }
%>
```

I tried to get data from the database called emidwify for the drop down options. But while I run my jsp file on localhost it showed that exception.

```
wrong entry java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/emidwify?user=root&password=root
```

Can anybody help me to solve it. I cannot trigger anything.

Note: I'm working on Linux mint. And I'm using spring java mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mysql jar file not loaded ...

Try putting the driver jar in the server lib folder

Add below dependancy in pom.xml

```
    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>  <!-- set your version -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you explain further. I'm exact beginer for this stuff

Comment: have added mysql-connector-java jar file?

Comment: Should I add it to jre system library? I downloaded mtsql-connector-java jar file and put it to a reference library folder

Comment: no need to download jar explicitly just add the dependency in pom.xml as shown in my edited anwer

Comment: what is  emidwify  in  jdbc:mysql://localhost/emidwify?user=root&password=root

Comment: is this port number ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127570/discussion-between-onkar-and-hasini-silva).

Comment: I could fix it. I've entered wrong mysql version. Thanks for your help.